# How can I mount a shelf above a closet door?

Tags: mounting, studs, shelving, closet

I would like to mount a wall shelf above a closet door in a small bedroom.

I was thinking about using the [Ikea Ekby shelf](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/40250841/), which is 59" long (exactly the length of the sliding doors of the closet). I don't know anything about how the wall is made and how to properly reinforce the shelf. (Ideally, even to hide the brackets completely.)

What is the best way to find out how these closets are made behind the drywall?

I have a magnetic studs detector and I know for sure that there are vertical metal studs on both sides of the closet. It looks like there's also a (wooden?) horizontal beam right above it.

What's the best way to properly fix the shelf?

[image: The closet]

Answer (score 2):

I did this once when I lived in an apartment and could not modify anything.

Since I had metal working and welding experience, I created a steel frame using 1 inch angle steel. Basically, it was a 'table' that stood inside the closet and it's dimensions where precisely the inside dimensions of the closet; ie; the legs were flush against the walls of the closet.

The 1 inch steel angle iron was small enough not to interfere with the closet itself and were strong enough to support the shelf (two pieces of 1/2 inch thick plywood; each 1/2 the width of the closet so they can the inserted).

I made the steel frame so that it could be assembled using screws once its put inside the closet.

When I moved out of that apartment, I easily removed the shelf assembly and viola! I had a un-modified closet to return to the landlord.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks!
Just to make sure I understand you correctly, was the shape of the frame like П? I.e. the load would be go to the floor through the sides of the frame and the top would hold the shelves themselves?

Comment: That is correct. I forgot to mention that I had welded plates to the bottom of the legs so that the angle iron would not dig into the hardwood floor.